# Invalid Variant Operation

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Using Windows 7 64 and Delphi 2010

We are calling a 3rd party function: EFTTerminal.Purchase(1,0) which make a purchase of $1 from a EFTPOS terminal.

Whenever this is called we always get "Invalid Variant Operation".

EFTTerminal.Purchase(1,0). I believe that the parameters are Variant type as the following all compile ok.

```
EFTTerminal.Purchase(1,0)
EFTTerminal.Purchase('1','0')
EFTTerminal.Purchase(1.5,1.5)
```

But all give the same error.

When I break it is in this procedure in the Variants unit.

```
procedure VarInvalidOp;
begin
raise EVariantInvalidOpError.Create(SInvalidVarOp);
end;
```

The 3rd party can't/won't give us the source code so we are unable to trace this any further.

Can anyone give me some clues on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Just because multiple input value types are accepted does not necessarily mean that `Variant` is being used.  `Purchase()` could simply be overloaded for multiple data types. You have to know the definition in order to call it, so how is `Purchase()` actually declared? You don't need to full source code to get that info.

Comment: What is `EFTTerminal` actually declared as?  Is it a class, a DLL, a COM object, ...?

Comment: What does the full call stack look like in the debugger when `VarInvalidOp()` is called?

Comment: Thanks Remy I have requested the declaration of this function from 3rd party.

Comment: Has the 3rd party done anything to help you troubleshoot this yet? It is their library. If they can't help you, I would suggest finding another EFTPOS library, or even write your own ETFPOS communication code directly (EFTPOS specifications are available from terminal vendors - I have one such spec from PC-EFTPOS Pty Ltd, for instance).

Comment: You don't need to ask the 3rd party for the declaration. Your Delphi already knows it, or else your code would not compile. So what is Delphi telling you the declaration looks like?

Answer (score -2):

All fixed.
It was an issue with Initialization of the object in my code.
Thanks for your suggestions Remy

Comment: This isn't really an answer or a question that will be useful to future vistors. You should just delete.